# Selecting the div immediately after the label

Tags: jquery

I need to add a class to the div immediately after the :first label.

My HTML is as such:

```
<label class="twc-first active">3DTV</label>
<div class="content mobile">
    <ul class="content">
    </ul>
    <h3>Secondary Topic Content</h3>
    <ul class="secondaryContent">
    </ul>
</div>

<label>Auto HD</label>
<div class="content">
    <ul class="content">
    </ul>
    <h3>Secondary Topic Content</h3>
    <ul class="secondaryContent">
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm already using jQuery to find the label:first and add the classes twc-first and active. What I need now is to grab the

```
<div class="content">
```

and make it:

```
<div class="content mobile">
```

immediately after that

```
<label class="twc-first active">.
```

I've tried multiple combinations of [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/), etc without luck.

I think this is close, but it definitely ain't no cigar. (first two lines are working splendidly at this point)

```
$('.twc-FAQTopics label:first').addClass('twc-first').addClass('active');
$('.twc-FAQTopics label:last').addClass('twc-last');

$('.twc-FAQTopics label:first').next('div.content').addClass('mobile');
```

Comment: This should work http://jsfiddle.net/brsvK/1

Comment: Incidentally, could I point out that a `label` is used to '[identify the caption for an item in a user-interface](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/label)', specifically used to associate text with a given `input` (or `textarea` or `select`) element; not as a heading. I think, from what I can see, that you should consider using one of the heading elements, `h1` to `h6` (probably not `h1` though, given you've two of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.next()` to find the div from the label. I don't see any reason to use `:first` as a selector though since the first label already has a class, which the second one does not.

```
$('label.twc-first').next('div.content').addClass('someClass');
```

[See the behavior here](http://jsfiddle.net/z2tQV/5/)

Comment: Forgot the `.` after the initial selector :)

Comment: `find()` only looks at descendants, not siblings. Consider re-reading the [API](http://api.jquery.com/find/).

Comment: @MohammadAdil I had `find` at first and stupidly changed it to closest. I've since updated.

Comment: The `div` is a sibling of the `label`, not an ancestor (`closest()`) or a descendant (`find()`). Seriously, check the API.

Comment: Why are you hiding it and isn't your latest edit what the OP already tried?

Comment: I OP posted also works... see musa's comment on question - http://jsfiddle.net/brsvK/1

Comment: Awesome! Yes that did work, but I discovered that part of the problem I was having was with my Order of Operations. Long story short; I am using .insertAfter to place that div.content and I was trying to force the .addClass prior to that. Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: @evan No - I'd mark it up, but I don't have a high enough reputation just yet

Answer (score 1):

[`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) ***only*** works if the `div` is immediately after the `label`.

If there is another element between the `label` and the `div`, it will not work. 

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uPHk6/6/

Otherwise, you will have to use [`.nextAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/):

`$('label:first').nextAll('div:eq(0)').addClass('classHere')`

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uPHk6/7/

---

***UPDATE:***

You can also use the [`Next Siblings Selector (~)`](http://api.jquery.com/next-siblings-selector/):

```
//without :first in div:first, it will return all subsequent divs
$('label:first ~ div:first').addClass('classHere');
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/uPHk6/10/

Comment: Dom, thanks for explaining the diff between .next() and .nextAll() - helpful as well